# Nunit loads all test Test data for all the test before the test gets executed

Tags: xml, c#-4.0, nunit

I am using Nunit. It loads all test Test data for all the test before the test gets executed.I just want to why is this happening . I want to if there is any other effective way to load data.I have posted the code i use below and data source is xml

```
    private IEnumerable Example
{
    get { return GetExample; }
}
private IEnumerable GetExample()
{
    var doc = XDocument.Load("Example.xml");
    return
        from Examples in doc.Descendants("Example")
        let Example1 = Examples.Attribute("Example1").Value
        let Example2 = Examples.Attribute("Example2").Value
        let Example3 = Examples.Attribute("Example3").Value

        select new object[] { Example1, Example2, Example3};
}
[TestCaseSource("Example")]
public void ShouldLogin(string username, string password, bool expected)
{
    // just test that uses the data from above 
}
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Examples>
  <Example Example1="fsse" Example2="dj7sihfs" Example3="true" />
  <Example Example1="hgtd" Example2="sd122?=s" Example3="true" />
  <Example Example1="asde" Example2="!!sf3mff" Example3="true" />
  <Example Example1="bsfd" Example2="--sdfj+?" Example3="true" />
  <Example Example1="aefb" Example2="!#¤%/(sd" Example3="true" />

</Examples>
```

It loads the same data twice when when two different test calls the same test data
Thank u for your help in advance

Comment: You're not providing *how* your GetExample is invoked.  Where GetExample is located in an NUnit text fixture defines when/how often it will be executed.  Please provide the entire text fixture that uses this code.

Answer (score 0):

I think that's by design. NUnit is designed to clean up the environment before any test, to generate same conditions for any test independent their execution order.

If Test A would change the XDocument, Test B would be run with that changes. That might led to indeterminate test results.

If Test B expects changes made from Test A, then your tests are not fully isolated, that's a bad practice.

If you wan't to change that behaviour, implement a lazy field and load the test data only on first access. You can increase performance if you know that you are not changing data in any of your tests, but pay attention.

```
private static Lazy<IEnumerable> testData = new Lazy<IEnumerable>(GetExample); 

private static IEnumerable GetExample() {
    var doc = XDocument.Load("Example.xml");
    return
        from Examples in doc.Descendants("Example")
        let Example1 = Examples.Attribute("Example1").Value
        let Example2 = Examples.Attribute("Example2").Value
        let Example3 = Examples.Attribute("Example3").Value

        select new object[] { username, password, expected };
}
```

You can also use TestFixtureSetupAttribute

```
private IEnumerable testData; 

[TestFixtureSetUp]
public void LoadTestData() {
    testData = GetExample();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining to me why all the test are loaded initially before the test are executed ,but when i used the lazy loading like you suggested i get a `System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException : Parameter count mismatch.` error